# Script to output a string that contains a different matching string from a flat file

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I need a script that reads from a flat file and outputs the first string of the row when there is matching string on that row.

For example.

File 'servers.txt' contains:

```
Server1:12.345.678.99:servertest99.test.com
Server2:12.345.678.98:servertest98.test.com
Server3:12.345.678.97:servertest97.test.com
```

Commands:

```
# ./script.sh -i 12.345.678.99
# Server1

#./script.sh -h servertest98.test.com
# Server2
```

I'm stuck... Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `awk`, you could say:

```
awk -F: '$2~/pattern_to_match/{print $1}' filename
```

For example, saying

```
awk -F: '$2~/12.345.678.99/{print $1}' inputfile
```

would result in

```
Server1
```

---

Using `sed`, you could say:

```
sed -nr '/pattern/s/(\w+).*/\1/p' inputfile
```

Comment: This answers the question as asked, but I suspect the OP is really looking for `'$2 ~ /pattern/ ... '`

Comment: Thank you for the quick response!  I'll give this a shot.  I am very new to scripting and am having a hard time with this.

Answer (score 0):

write a script named script.sh

```
    grep $1 servers.txt| cut -f1 -d":"
```

run as follows:

chmod +x script.sh

./script.sh pattern

e.g.
./script.sh 12.345.678.99